# Make clang-format break after the usage of C++ attributes

Tags: c++, c++14, clang-format

I'm using a [deprecated attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated) in my code and I haven't found a [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) documented way to break after the C++ attribute. I would like that the definition of the `do_not_use()` function starts on a next line after the `[[deprecated]]` attribute.

Is there a way to break after C++ attributes?

Current state:

```
[[deprecated("Will be removed in version 2.3.0 as it doesn't support "
             "multi-threading processing. "
             "Use mt_process_info() instead")]] void
do_not_use()
{
    std::cout << "This function should not be used" << std::endl;
}
```

Desired state:

```
[[deprecated("Will be removed in version 2.3.0 as it doesn't support "
             "multi-threading processing. "
             "Use mt_process_info() instead")]]
void do_not_use()
{
    std::cout << "This function should not be used" << std::endl;
}
```

.clang-format:

```
Language: Cpp
Standard: c++20
AccessModifierOffset: 0
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
    AfterCaseLabel: true
    AfterClass: true
    AfterControlStatement: true
    AfterEnum: true
    AfterFunction: true
    AfterNamespace: true
    AfterStruct: true
    BeforeCatch: true
    BeforeElse: true
    IndentBraces: false
    SplitEmptyFunction: true
ColumnLimit: 100
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentAccessModifiers: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth: 4
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
UseTab: Never
```

I've tried fiddling with the `AttributeMacros` and `StatementAttributeLikeMacros` `clang-format` settings but I haven't found a solution for stated problem.

Comment: You can use `//  clang-format off` / `//  clang-format on` to force the formatting you want.

Answer (score 2):

Good news, a very recent clang-format commit (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/a28f0747c2f3728bd8a6f64f7c8ba80b4e0cda9f) has added a new format option: `BreakAfterAttributes`.

Using `BreakAfterAttributes: Always` gives the output you want:

```bash
clang-format --style="{BreakAfterAttributes: Always}"
```

```cpp
[[deprecated("Will be removed in version 2.3.0 as it doesn't support "
             "multi-threading processing. "
             "Use mt_process_info() instead")]]
void do_not_use() {
  std::cout << "This function should not be used" << std::endl;
}
```

Since this option is so new, it isn't yet in any *released* version, but it is guaranteed to be in version 16, or you may build clang-format from source.